# Multiprocessing slower than sequential with python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I've invested quite a lot of time in rewriting my code to exploit more cores, but when I benchmarked it I found that all I had achieved was making it 7 times slower than the original code, despite running on 16 cores rather than one! This leads me to believe that I must be doing something wrong.

The code is 4000+ lines and needs a number of pretty heavy input files, so I'm not going to be able to post something that reproduces the problem. However, I can say that the function that I'm calling typically takes 0.1s to run and calls some c libraries using ctypes. It is also passed a fair amount of data in memory - maybe 1 MB? Some pseudo code that looks like the slow bit:

```
    def AnalyseSection(Args):
        Sectionsi,SectionNo,ElLoads,ElLoadsM,Materials,CycleCount,FlapF,EdgeF,Scaling,Time,FlapFreq,EdgeFreq=Args
        for i in range(len(Sections[Elements])):
           #Do some heavy lifting with ctypes
        return Result

     for i in range(10):
         for j in range(10):
             for k in range(10):
                 Args=[(Sections[i],SectionList[i],ElLoads,ElLoadsM,Materials,CycleCount,FlapF,EdgeF,Scaling,Time,FlapFreq,EdgeFreq) for n in SectionList]
                 pool=mp.Pool(processes=NoCPUs,maxtasksperchild=1)
                 result = pool.map(AnalyseSection,Args)
                 pool.close()
                 pool.join()
```

I was hoping someone could spot an obvious error that's causing it to run so much more slowly? The function takes a while to run (0.1s for each call typically) so I'd not think that the overhead associated with multiprocessing could slow it down so much. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Starting threads(as well as processes) consumes a _lot_ of time. It may be not your code that is slow but the spawning of processes.

Comment: what's the size of `SectionList` as it seems your `Args` will have size of  `SectionList` tuples in them meaning you will start size of `Args` by 16 subprocesses which can potentially be a lot? also what does it mean 'takes a while to run' ballpark figure may be useful? Next on the list is the question what's your bottleneck? Are you not hitting disk i/o hard?

Comment: @user3012759 - Takes 'a while to run' is of the order of 0.1s for the problem I'm running at the moment. At least that's my estimate - I timed the whole thing without multiprocessing and 16 sections (the thing that's analysed by AnalyseSection(Args), and 16 is a coincidence - nothing to do with the number of CPUs) takes between 1 and 2 seconds without multiprocessing and 7 and 8 seconds with it. There is no writing to disk but as I intimated I may be accessing a fair bit of RAM. Could ctypes be reading the libraries from disk every time? They're only about 20kB anyway, but over a network.

Comment: SectionList is a list, typically of size 20-40. I couldn't find any other way of passing multiple arguments to the pool.map() function apart from creating a lsit of the arguments.

Comment: what about heavy input files? where are they being read?

Comment: also with 10*10*10*~2*16 you're creating approx 32k subprocesses... it will not be the best use of cpu time if you're spending 0.1s in a process, you can try to re-shuffle the code a bit to cut your forks to something like 32? and see if this will improve speed

Comment: @user3012759. The heavy input files are read in before the multiprocessing bit starts and broken down to be passed to AnalyseSection(), so at any one time the amount of data being moved around shouldn't be too much. I did consider parallelizing the loop above the current one, but my results in moving parallelisation from the loop below the current one (ie the loop in AnalyseSection() to the current loop) have been discouraging! I think it has actually got worse, or at least not much better. That was why I was wondering if my implementation was wrong somehow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72668/discussion-between-peter-greaves-and-user3012759).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
 for i in range(10):
     for j in range(10):
         for k in range(10):
             Args=[(Sections[i],SectionList[i],ElLoads,ElLoadsM,Materials,CycleCount,FlapF,EdgeF,Scaling,Time,FlapFreq,EdgeFreq) for n in SectionList]
             pool=mp.Pool(processes=NoCPUs,maxtasksperchild=1)
             result = pool.map(AnalyseSection,Args)
             pool.close()
             pool.join()
```

can and should be transformed to this

```
 pool=mp.Pool(processes=NoCPUs)

 for i in range(10):
     for j in range(10):
         for k in range(10):
             Args=[(Sections[i],SectionList[i],ElLoads,ElLoadsM,Materials,CycleCount,FlapF,EdgeF,Scaling,Time,FlapFreq,EdgeFreq) for n in SectionList]
             result = pool.map(AnalyseSection,Args)

 pool.join()
```

This is more in line with what you are trying to achieve. You have a multiprocessing Pool where you feed the data and wait for the results. You don't have to start/stop the pool in each iteration.

Keep in mind that there is a cost associated with starting processed (much bigger than threads, if you are used to threads).

Comment: Thanks, you posted up what @user3012759 helped me to work up. This works, I thought I had tried this in the past and it hadn't worked but I must have been mistaken.